# How can I add Reformat Code option to Right Click context menu in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, contextmenu

How can I add "Reformat Code" option to Right Click context menu in Android Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by:

1. Open Preferences (or File -> Settings on Windows)
2. Go to Appearance and Behaviour -> Menus and Toolbars
3. Uncollapse the Editor Popup Menu
4. Click on an item in this list that you want to add Reformat Code command next to
5. Click Add After button
6. In the Choose Actions dialog, click All Actions -> Main Menu -> Code -> Reformat Code, then click OK.
7. Click OK to dismiss preferences dialog, and you should see Reformat code in the code editor window context menu.

These instructions are for Android Studio 3 on MacOS, I know it is the same on Android Studio 2.3.1 on Windows, could be it's a bit different in other versions.

The relevant section of IntelliJ (on which Android Studio is based) help is here - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-menus-and-toolbars.html

Comment: Awesome, it worked perfectly. Are you a developer in  Android Studio team?

Comment: No, I just wanted to do the same thing :-)

Answer (score 0):

that menu is the IDE menu you cannot change what's given there
you can Autoident("reformat code") code using:

Win

Ctrl + Alt + L
Linux:

Ctrl + Shift + Alt + L
Mac:

Option + Command + L

You can also use Eclipse shortcuts. Windows and Linux, go to File > Settings > Keymap , Mac OS X, go to > Preferences > Keymap and choose Eclipse from the dropdown menu.